# Relative log file matching with linux?

Tags: awk, grep, vim, logs

I already know how to use `grep` or `awk` to match something in a log file, but is there a way to do the following?

1. Match a specific line in a file...and include it in the result.
2. From the matched line from (1.) in the file, go up until a second string is matched and include it as well as all the lines between in the result.
3. And then with a third match start searching from the match (1.) down a third string is matched and include it as well as all the lines between in the result.

This way if what is being searched for is in the context of a BEGINNING and an END you can search for just the context that what you were searching for occurred in.
The log file looks like this:

```
<several-1000-lines>
...[BEGINX]
some log a
<several-1000-lines>
...[First-string-i-search-for]
<several-1000-lines>
some log b
...[ENDX]
<several-1000-lines>
```

and then I would get something like this as output after searching for `[First-string-i-search-for]`:

```
...[BEGINX]
some log a
<several-1000-lines>
...[First-string-i-search-for]
<several-1000-lines>
some log b
...[ENDX]
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to start with #2, unless you really want the lines in reverse order

Comment: BEGIN and END are non repeated lines?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity They are repeated in the file yes, but not between the `[BEGINX]` and `[ENDX]` lines.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity And it's possible that there is more than one match from `(1.)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep` that support PCRE ([Perl-compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)):

```
grep -Pzo '.*\[BEGINX\](.|\n)*?\[First-string-i-search-for\](.|\n)*?\[ENDX\].*\n' infile
```

that is:

```
grep -Pzo '.*BEGINNING(.|\n)*?MIDDLE(.|\n)*?END.*\n' infile
```

Comment: To be clear, in addition to only working if you have GNU grep available, that's not looking for strings, it's doing regexp matching and it would have to read the whole file into memory so YMMV with different input and/or different search stings plus `-P` and `-z` don't play nice together - see the man page (https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) `-P Interpret patterns as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs)....but consider this option experimental when combined with the -z (--null-data) option`.

Comment: @EdMorton So this is a use with caution, because if it matches too much of a truly giant log file it's going to make the machine run out of memory?

The log file I'm working with is rather short, but this is good to know.

Comment: It's not that it matches too much, it's that it has to read the whole file into memory before matching anything so yes, it will fail for a file that's too big to fit in memory. It also may not work at all because, according to the people who provide the tool, `-P` and `-z` together are "experimental" and it wont work on other Unix boxes that don't have GNU awk. You'll also have to be carefule with what characters appear in the "string" you want to search for as they're being used as regexps, not strings. So overall - YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    beg = "[BEGINX]"
    mid = "[First-string-i-search-for]"
    end = "[ENDX]"
}
index($0,beg) {
    gotBeg = 1
    gotMid = 0
    buf = ""
}
gotBeg {
    buf = buf $0 ORS
    if ( index($0,mid) ) {
        gotMid = 1
    }
    if ( index($0,end) ) {
        if ( gotMid ) {
            printf "%s", buf
        }
        gotBeg = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
...[BEGINX]
some log a
<several-1000-lines>
...[First-string-i-search-for]
<several-1000-lines>
some log b
...[ENDX]
```

The above assumes:

1. The 3 strings you want to search for always appear on different lines from each other.
2. You always want to test from the last BEGINX to the first ENDX after it.

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed using the range operator we store the block in hold space. And at the end line, check whether the string exists in the block so that we may print.

```
sed -n '
  /\[BEGINX]/!d
  :loop
    H;n
  /\[ENDX]/!bloop
  H;z;x
  /\[First-string-i-search-for]/p
' file
```

---

Using the range operator `,` we can solve it like as:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { str = "[First-string-i-search-for]" }

  /\[BEGINX]/, /\[ENDX]/ {a[++n]=$0}

  n==1               {seen=0;next}
  n && index($0,str) {seen++;next}
  n && /\[ENDX]/     {flush(seen)}

  function flush(flag,  i) {
    if (flag) for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]
    n = split("", a, ":")
  }
' file
...[BEGINX]
some log a
<several-1000-lines>
...[First-string-i-search-for]
<several-1000-lines>
some log b
...[ENDX]
```